# How to calculate X and Y coordinates given an angle and varying side lengths

Tags: google-maps, geometry, trigonometry, computational-geometry, geofencing

I am building a Google Maps Javascript API application that allows the user to draw a path of multiple polylines, calculates the angles, then attempts to curve the angles, simulating a vehicle turning radius. In order to do this, I need the point the curve starts and stops at. The problem is that these angles can be in any assortment of directions on a map, and I am struggling to find the appropriate way to calculate the (X,Y) coordinates of these points... I can calculate the magnitude, but due to the varying orientation, am not sure how to get it back to a set of cartesian coordinates. Here is an outline of the geometry:

[image: geomtetry]

Ultimately, I have points A, B, and C, angle a, and the radius of the circle. Given that, how can I calculate points P1, P2, and (not labeled) the green reference points for the bezier curve in terms of cartesian coordinates? These points do not have to be specific, just in the general area to guide the curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make vectors `BA` and `BС`

```
BA.x = A.x-B.x
BA.y = A.y-B.y etc
```

Make unit vectors

```
len(BA) = sqrt(BA.x*BA.x+BA.y*BA.y)
uBA = BA / len(BA)       (uBA.x = BA.x/len(BA) etc)
uBC = BC / len(BC)
```

Get cosine of angle between vectors

```
cs = cos(fullangle) = dot(uBA, uBC) = uBA.x*uBC.x + uBA.y*ubC.y
```

Get tangent of half-angle

```
tn = sqrt((1-cs)/(1+cs))
```

Calculate points to provide normal distance `R` from bisector to lines

```
P1 = B + uBA * R / tn   (P1.x = B.x + uBA.x * R / tn   etc)
P2 = B + uBC * R / tn
```

Note that smooth conjugation of Bezier curve and lines requires control points **on lines**, so

```
C1 = P1 - uBA * R * coeff
C2 = P2 - uBC * R * coeff
```

Where coefficient should be adapted for "smart curve" look, perhaps in range 0.3..1.

```
coeff=0.552
```

for right-angled lines gives almost perfect circle arc.

In general

```
coeff = 4/3*tg(angle/4)
```

is nice approximantion

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am wondering though with the dot product, for uBA.x, uBC.x, etc... should I use one point, or the difference? Since they are unit vectors, wouldn't the difference be 1? So it would always be 2 if using the difference. Want to make sure I am understanding that part correctly.

Comment: Added some explanations of vector stuff

Comment: cs and tn - single scalar values, not vectors

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me after 2 weeks of constantly fighting with the geometry.